# Handoff method not being called when opening app on iPhone via apple watch

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, watchkit, apple-watch

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
    continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity
      restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *__nullable restorableObjects))restorationHandler
```

This method is not being called when I get a push notification to my apple watch and then open the app on the iPhone via handoff icon at the bottom of the screen.

What method can I rely on being called when my app launches via the apple watch. My app doesn't have a watch app.

Comment: I don't get this question. if your app doesn't have a Watch app, how are you receiving PN on it and expect to hand it off? What am i missing?

Comment: @AceGreen If your app doesn't have an apple watch app you still get a notification on the apple watch. If you open your app's notification on the watch then look at your phone you see the handoff icon on the lock screen.

Answer (score 0):

If your app doesn't have a watch app, `continueUserActivity` is not called. When your watch app call the following method, `continueUserActivity` is called on iPhone.

```
- (void)updateUserActivity:(NSString *)type
    userInfo:(nullable NSDictionary *)userInfo
    webpageURL:(nullable NSURL *)webpageURL;
```

Comment: So is their no way to make the phone app do something when you open via apple watch without an apple watch app?